# Twitter 404 Error -- invalid URI requested or requested format not supported?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I am retrieving the followers of a couple of Twitter seed accounts, and then the followers of those followers -- but for some reason when I attempt to retrieve the followers of the followers by iterating through the list of user ID's, a 404 error is returned (URI requested is invalid or resource requested, such as a user, does not exist. Also returned when the requested format is not supported by the requested method):

```
for(int k = 0; k < secondLevel.size(); k++) //secondLevel = arraylist of strings containing user ids
  {
try{ 
String IDs = twitter.getFollowersIDs(secondLevel.get(k),-1).toString();
IDs = IDs.substring(IDs.indexOf("[")); //remove description before json 
try{
  followerArray = new org.json.JSONArray(IDs);
}
```

I also tried converting all the user id's to screen names and iterating through that array, but the exception is just thrown during that segment of code instead (while looking up each user).

```
String[] secondLevelNames = new String[secondLevel.size()];
  for(int l = 0; l < secondLevel.size(); l++) //changes ids to screennames
  {
    try{
      User user = twitter.showUser(secondLevel.get(l));
      secondLevelNames[l] = user.getScreenName(); }
```

Clearly these users exist because I retrieved them from the list of followers for existing Twitter accounts. I also attempted to debug by printing out the screen names that were claimed to be nonexistent and looked them up manually; they are all valid users. Any idea of where the error is coming from? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what API version your are using? this is may happen about the API version hosting url

Comment: @jothikannan: the most recent one, I just started this project a week ago.